# How to install gnome shell 3.6 in debian 7.1

Tags: debian, gnome3, upgrade, gnome-shell

I have installed Debian 7.1 and I realized it has installed gnome shell 3.4.2. How can I upgrade it to version 3.6?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution. Actually Debian has not any stable version of gnome shell 3.6. It is only in experimental version. Stay tuned!

Comment: As a matter of policy Debian lags behind other distros with version updates; the premise is that the this is what makes the "stable" repo stable.  Stuff has to be in "testing" for a while first.